# Excavated cylinder rolling down ramp

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

I am wondering about this problem. I have a uniform cylinder of radius $a$ with a hole of radius $a/2$ in it which rolls without slipping down a fixed, inclined plane and I want to know it's speed at the bottom of the incline.

[image: nonuniform object on inclined plan]

I want to use
$$ mgh = \frac{1}{2}mv_\text{cm}^2 + \frac{1}{2}I_\text{cm}\omega^2 $$
and then $I_\text{cm} = kma^2$ and $v_\text{center}=r\omega$ as you would for the case without the hole although I don't know how to relate $v_\text{center}$ to $v_{cm}$. Is this still the correct approach to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no slipping happening, the moment of inertia around the contact point will vary on the angle of rotation. So you will need to find the total angle of rotation $\varphi = \frac{h}{2\pi a\sin\alpha}$ and find the $I(\phi)$ first.

Moreover, since centre of mass is offset from the centre of cylinder, the potential energy depends on $\varphi$ too. When the point of contact will lower down by $h$, the centre of mass may lower smaller or greater height.

Finally, at small angles $\alpha<\alpha_c$ the cylinder won't roll down at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that this problem can be simplified if you choose a height that puts the orientation of the hole at the bottom the same as at the top. Then you can work with the center of the cylinder instead of the center of mass.  (v = Rω)  To get the (I) relative to the center, subtract the I associated with the material that was removed from the hole from the normal (I) (using the parallel axis theorem).